# Unsupported media type using RestSharp library

Tags: c#, restsharp

I start using RestSharp library to connect my Windows Forms application with web.

I created a method like this:

```
public static bool WebRequest(string route, string token, Method method, string model)
{
    var client = new RestClient("myapiurl");
    var request = new RestRequest(route, method);

    //"model" is a json
    request.AddParameter("application/json", model, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    var content = response.Content;

    return true;
}
```

The request has 3 parameters:

```
{ application/json={ "CommunicationType":4854,"JobNumber":55555,"NotificationAddress":"(714) 978-9788","CreatedBy":"user@mail.com","IsDeleted":false } }
{ Accept=application/json }
{ Authorization=Bearer dasjd... }
```

But the response always returns:

> StatusCode: UnsupportedMediaType

I didn't see anything wrong in my request, can someone see what is wrong?

Regards

Comment: You need to add header `Content-Type` with value `application\json`

Answer (score 1):

Add need to add  content type in header

```
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
```

[get reference GetOrPost:ParameterTypes for RestRequest](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/ParameterTypes-for-RestRequest#getorpost)

> RequestBody If this parameter is set, its value will be sent as the
>   body of the request. Only one RequestBody parameter is accepted - the
>   first one.
>
> The name of the parameter will be used as the Content-Type header for
>   the request.
>
> RequestBody does not work on GET or HEAD Requests, as they do not
>   actually send a body.
>
> If you have GetOrPost parameters as well, they will overwrite the
>   RequestBody - RestSharp will not combine them but it will instead
>   throw the RequestBody parameter away.
>
> It is recommended to use `AddJsonBody` or `AddXmlBody` methods instead of
>   AddParameter with type BodyParameter. Those methods will set the
>   proper request type and do the serialization work for you.

I think you need to add

```
request.AddJsonBody(model); // AddJsonBody serializes the object automatically
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is encountering this, but for GET requests. I was encountering this same error and only saw answers saying a variation of the following solution to fix the Unsupported Media Type issue

```
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
```

For GET requests, you can also encounter this same error if you have the incorrect setting for Accept-Encoding. For my case, the API was only supporting gzip, so it was rejecting the default values that RestSharp was sending for Accept-Encoding header, which was gzip, deflate, br. The solution that worked for me was setting this Rest Client option:

```
var options = new RestClientOptions(url)
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
};
    
_client = new RestClient(options);
```